# Como hacer para que un hilo se repita

Tags: android

Trato de implementar un `hilo` que corre junto al principal, este hilo se `ejecuta en 20 segundos`, necesito que después de finalizar el hilo `nuevamente vuelva a ejecutarse` de forma continua.

Con este código el hilo se ejecuta una vez, pero como hago para que vuelva a ejecutarse.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
.
.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
.
.
    treadTimer();
}

private void treadTimer(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=1; i<= 20; i++){
                try{
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tarea Larga Finalizada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poner todo el código dentro de `run()` dentro de un `while(condition)`. Si quieres que se ejecute por siempre, como condición pones `true`, sino pon una condición.

Esto hará que todo lo que hace tu `Thread` se ejecute continuamente sin bloquear toda la aplicación.

#### Ejemplo *(Creo que en tu aplicación seria algo así)*:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
.
.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
.
.
    treadTimer();
}

private void treadTimer(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                for(int i=1; i<= 20; i++){
                    try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch (InterruptedException e){}
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tarea Larga Finalizada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```